# No such file or directory find command on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, debian, cron

I've created script which delete old backup file from directory but this command was worked fine before 1 week and Nothing change on script or packages but still getting below error:

```
root@:# find /var/backups/abc/* -type d -mtime +6
/var/backups/abc/2016-03-09_0321

root@:~# find /var/backups/abc/* -type d -mtime +6 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: `/var/backups/abc/2016-03-08_0321': No such file or directory
```

Problem is that, this script run every day on cron, I getting a mail like " find: `/var/backups/abc/2016-03-08_0321': No such file or directory". files are deleted but such a mails are getting from root.

Answer (score 4):

```
find /var/backups/abc/* -type d -mtime +6 -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Here, we use `-prune` on the directories that we're about to delete, so `find` will then not try to read their contents.

Comment: #Toby Speight, i have edited the Answer as per your suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks It's working....

Answer (score 2):

This is because of after having returned your directory, find will try to look in it (to continue his recursive search), and will fail because of you just removed it.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Comment: Yes. The solution is to use -prune and is described in this post:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/delete-files-and-directories-by-their-names-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @TomMagis, should _after having returned your directory_ be in fact _after having **removed/deleted** your directory_?