# Strategies against find looking for directories removed by `-exce rm`

Tags: bash

## the situation

To get all `__pycache__` directories I use this:

```
$ find . -type d -name __pycache__
./files/__pycache__
$
```

To remove them I use `-exec`:

```
$ find . -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -fr {} \;
find: './files/__pycache__': No such file or directory
$
```

I get this strange ``No such file or directory, but anyway the remove is done:

```
$ find . -type d -name __pycache__
$
```

## xargs alternative, danger and cure

In the meantime I use `xargs`:

```
$ find . -type d -name __pycache__ | xargs rm -fr
```

As suggested by @jonathan-leffler -r (aka --no-run-if-empty) prevent executing the command once even if there are no names read from standard input, so better

```
$ find . -type d -name __pycache__ | xargs -r rm -fr
```

## notes:

- This [No such file or directory find command on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36003434/3313834) closed question is related but as @jeff-holt said does no give the understanding of the `-depth` option. Anyway -prune solution is very counter-intuitive in regard a catch directories and have an action on them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such file or directory find command on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36003434/no-such-file-or-directory-find-command-on-linux)

Comment: If you use the -d flag (force find to perform a depth-first traversal), then the nuisance is avoided. The above link, closed, has a solution of -prune that doesn't go the same direction of understanding as -d does.

Comment: You can get that error if there were two invocations of `rm -fr ./files/__pycache__` for some reason: the first succeeds so the second fails. It is less than obvious, though, how that could happen here. In general, it's feasible and usually a good idea to use `+` in place of `\;` — that allows `find` to group names so that the command is executed less often. That shouldn't have mattered here. It is odd that it occurred. My gut feel is it won't reproduce on your machine reliably — and I'd probably dismiss it as "weird — I'll worry if it happens again next time". If it does reproduce — details!

Comment: Note that [`xargs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html) has the annoying, POSIX-mandated habit of executing the command once even if there are no names read from standard input.  GNU `xargs` has an option `-r` (aka `--no-run-if-empty`) to prevent that happening.